# How to select multiple option automatically in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, jquery-plugins, bootstrap-selectpicker

I am using multi-select picker. I want to automatically select options on ajax response.

I have data in this form

```
tuesday,wednesday,Thursday
```

here is a select picker

```
<select class="form-control kt-selectpicker" multiple="" name="operation_day[]" tabindex="-98">
                                    <option value="monday" >Monday</option>
                                    <option value="tuesday">Tuesday</option>
                                    <option value="wednesday" >Wednesday</option>
                                    <option value="thursday" >Thursday</option>
                                    <option value="friday">Friday</option>
                                    <option value="saturday" >Saturday</option>
                                    <option value="sunday" >Sunday</option>
</select>
```

this is the variable which is having data

```
var operation_day = editData.attr('data-operation_day');
```

How i can automatically select those option which are in variable with help of jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.split(",")` to convert them in array and then set value using `selectpicker('val', operation_day.split(","))` lastly refresh your selectpicker.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var operation_day = "tuesday,wednesday,thursday";
console.log(operation_day.split(","))
$('select').selectpicker('val', operation_day.split(",")); //split them and set value
$('select').selectpicker('refresh') //refresh ..selectpicker
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control kt-selectpicker" multiple="" name="operation_day[]" tabindex="-98">
  <option value="monday">Monday</option>
  <option value="tuesday">Tuesday</option>
  <option value="wednesday">Wednesday</option>
  <option value="thursday">Thursday</option>
  <option value="friday">Friday</option>
  <option value="saturday">Saturday</option>
  <option value="sunday">Sunday</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the array for multiple selections like below.

```js
var operation_day = "tuesday,wednesday,thursday" //editData.attr('data-operation_day');
var arr = operation_day.split(',');
$(".kt-selectpicker").val(arr)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control kt-selectpicker" multiple="" name="operation_day[]" tabindex="-98">
  <option value="monday">Monday</option>
  <option value="tuesday">Tuesday</option>
  <option value="wednesday">Wednesday</option>
  <option value="thursday">Thursday</option>
  <option value="friday">Friday</option>
  <option value="saturday">Saturday</option>
  <option value="sunday">Sunday</option>
</select>
```

*Note: It's case sensitive. `thursday` is not equal to `Thursday`.*